# What do I do with a lighter that doesn't light?

Tags: repair

This is a fairly "traditional" lighter that's about a foot long and has a guarded trigger with a thumb switch one must push forward in order to light. Even with the adjustment set all the way to "+" and pushing the thumb switch forward and repeatedly clicking the trigger, it doesn't light.  There is a small clear window showing that there's plenty of fluid still left (probably >3/4 full).  What's the appropriate thing to do with this?

Comment: Throw it away and get a new one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a lighter is not Home Improvement.

Answer (score 1):

**Throw it away and get a new one.**
This is a "default" answer, also given by Tyler Durden as a comment, but other answers (including those discussing safe/environmentally responsible disposal) are welcome.